# I have TSA PRE for a couple of years, and now have NEXUS: What do I use for known traveller ID?

Tags: tsa-precheck, nexus, trusted-traveler

Does my old known traveller number (KTN) still work now that I have nexus?

Comment: Has your PRE expired?

Comment: @robokaren no, my pre is still valid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.cbp.gov/travel/trusted-traveler-programs/nexus/tsa-pre%E2%9C%93%C2%AE

> If you are a NEXUS member or eligible Global Entry or SENTRI member, enter your membership number (PASS ID) in the “Known Traveler Number” field when booking reservations, or enter it into your frequent flyer profile with the airline.
>
> Your membership number is also located on the back of your Trusted Traveler card in the upper-left corner.

You can still do this even if you had another previously.